# What in this script is causing my window to minimize?

Tags: autohotkey

The goal of this simple script is to detect an idle interval when a specific program is in focus and then send a simple keystroke when that idle interval has passed. I'm running this script on 4 PC's and I'm getting unexpected results. Some PC's minimize the window when the script runs. Other PC's run it as expected. The script is identical on each PC.

I'm invoking this script by right clicking on the script (that is, not running a compiled exe version of it). Running it as administrator seems to achieve better results on some clients, on one it makes no difference and minimizes the window.

As stated, on some PC's the script works as intended. There are no error messages, it just causes my window to minimize. Nothing in that code, to my newb eyes, should cause the window to minimize.

````
#Persistent
    SetTimer, Timer_check,3000

    Timer_check:
        if WinActive("ahk_exe gta5.exe")
        {
            if (A_TimeIdlePhysical > 31301 && WinActive("ahk_exe gta5.exe")) {
                Gosub, keepActive
                ToolTip, We're currently idle TimeIdle is %A_TimeIdle% and TimeIdlePhysical is %A_TimeIdlePhysical%
                sleep 1000
                ToolTip
            }

            if (A_TimeIdle < 31301) {
                ToolTip
            }
        }
    return

keepActive: ; keep active sub.
    if WinActive("ahk_exe gta5.exe")
    {
        Send, {` down} ; Press the ` key to keep us active. It holds the key for 0.2 seconds.
        Sleep 200
        Send, {` up}
    }
return```
````

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to send the accent/backtick, which is default escape character in AHK (**`**). To fix this, send a different character or escape the escape character, like so:

```
Send, {`` down}
Sleep 200
Send, {`` up}
```

Without it being escaped, **it just sends the down- and up-keys**. The WinKey+down combination minimizes a non-maximized window and that may somehow be related to why you're seeing the game window occasionally minimized.

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm

---

**Edit:** Added script for testing

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, Timer_check, 3000

Timer_check:
If WinActive("ahk_exe gta5.exe") {
    If (A_TimeIdlePhysical > 31301 && WinActive("ahk_exe gta5.exe")) {
        Send , z
        ToolTip, We're currently idle TimeIdle is %A_TimeIdle% and TimeIdlePhysical is %A_TimeIdlePhysical%
        sleep 1000
        ToolTip
    }
    If (A_TimeIdle < 31301)
        ToolTip
}
Return
```

Comment: I've made this change and unfortunately it does not resolve the issue. I also changed it to just the Z key, same results. The window gets minimized on that PC.

Comment: Please check if the script above works. It removes the subroutine and sends a single `z`.

Comment: The revised script (unmodified by me) is still causing the GTA5.exe window to minimize 100% of the time on 4 PC's running the script. (The posted version is doing it on 2 of 4). Clearly I'm missing something, but what that missing something is, I have no idea. I have other scripts that work on GTA5, but wanted to do this one from scratch since there was no passive one that I found (as opposed to activated).

Comment: Hmmm, that is odd. Nothing in the script sends anything except `Send , z`. Are you certain there are no other scripts running and that this is the only code in the script?

Comment: Absolutely positive. What I don't understand is why I'm getting different results from the same exact script. Or why it would minimize. My theory is that AHK is throwing up an error but doesn't have an output for it, instead interrupting the window; not minimizing it but stealing focus to nothing. Is there a secret debug console I can see if this is the case?

Comment: As I don't see what could cause that behavior in the code, I'm afraid I don't have a solution for you. I don't think there is a debug console for ahk. If it were me, I would start over using `controlsend` so that it doesn't have to be the active window. If that works, I would add the extra bits with tooltips, etc.